# How to Pass a value from wix to Looker studio

Tags: looker-studio

Can anyone please help me with following doubt,

how to pass a value from wix to Looker studio and filter the dataset using that value to generate report from Looker studio.
The value which passing from wix is a user inputed postcode. Thanks in advance.

I have created API Credentials in Looker to integrate with the wix(followed chatgpt).But it didn't really work. I am new to this field.
It would be great help if anyone can help me guide how to pass a value from wix to looker studio.